How would you properly translate "poisonous books" into Latin?
I tried using Google Translate, which gave me "venenata libri", but when I tried to double-check this by translating this back into English it turned into "poisoned book", which is not what I want. "venenati libri" translates into "poisoned books", which is closer, but poisoned is still different from poisonous. Any suggestions?
Edited to clarify: yes, @Asteroides, I mean it in the sense of metaphorically noxious or harmful. Books that contain dangerous ideas.

In what sense do you mean it? Books that will physically poison you if you eat them? Or books that are metaphorically noxious or harmful?

Does this refer to books that contain ideas deemed dangerous and that are therefore kept under lock and key in a "poison cabinet" to be accessed only by authorized scholars as covered in the report "The Giftschrank" about such collections in German libraries?

Do you mean something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_Librorum_Prohibitorum ?

@Asteroides I mean books that are metaphorically harmful, with dangerous ideas.

@njuffa that would absolutely qualify as my intended meaning, yes.

@DanielT yes, but I'd rather stick with a Latin phrase that conjures the innate malefic properties of the books rather than just an external ban upon them.

@motegod According to the literature, the books kept in the Giftschrank of various German libraries were at times referred to by the Latin term remota, which rather prosaically describes them as books removed from general circulation.

@motegod Your use of "malefic" is quite apt, since maleficus can mean a poisoner, although it is probably more often used to mean a sorcerer. Whether that is a bug or a feature I leave to you to decide. Veneficus is another word for sorcerer, but it more often means poisoner.  I recommend libri venefici, for what it's worth.

Librī noxiī is a near-direct translation of "poisonous books."

quorum ius et officium est libros noxios tum inspiciendi tum praeveniendi


Librī quī in discrīmen addūcere possint is an older, potentially more idiomatic translation of "dangerous books." The word discrīmen appeared in a previous publication. You can risk trying the genitive if you need something shorter.

ut ab illis scriptis, ipso iure naturali exigente, caveant, quae fidem ac bonos mores in discrimen adducere possint


to beware, as required by the natural law itself, of writings that can endanger faith and morals

Most of what I found searching for "dangerous books" is related to the Index Librorum Prohibitorum. I assume using a subordinate clause is the best or else they would have used a single adjective.
